# I am trying to use map in my react redux app. but after using useDispatch, the console is showing error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I am working on an app, but I am getting errors in the console. I am sending the picture of the error, along with the code which causes the error. could anyone tell, me what causes this problem?

```
import React from 'react';
import { useSelector, shallowEqual } from 'react-redux';
import AddBook from './form';
import SingleBook from './singleBook';


const DisplayBooks = () => {
  const books = useSelector((state) => state.booksArray, shallowEqual);

  return (
    <div className="book-list">
      {books.map((book) => <SingleBook key={book.id} title={book.title} author={book.author} />)}
      <AddBook />
    </div>
  )
};

export default DisplayBooks;
```

Below I have pasted the console image.

[image of the console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ct57e.jpg)

Comment: Try { books ? books.map.... : null }. Looks like when you are getting books its initially undefined. Might have a bug where your useDispatch it making books undefined.

Comment: yes, you're right! useDispatch is making the book undefind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think so this line of code is causing the problem

```
const books = useSelector((state) => state.booksArray, shallowEqual)
```

Change it to,

```
const books = useSelector((state) => state.booksArray)
console.log(books) -> to check whether the books is an array or not
```

Comment: Thanks for your piece of code. It helped me find the problem. Actually, the books were undefined. because of a spelling mistake.

Comment: glad to help, but I guess when you are trying to access books using this line of code const books = useSelector((state) => state.booksArray, shallowEqual), you are returning 2 things states.bookArray and shallowEqual, but books will be equal to shallowEqual, that's how js works . I just wanted to ask whether this was a minor bug in your code or not ?